# Does the new Final Fantasy VII have native gamepad support?

Tags: pc, controllers, final-fantasy-7

Does the [new version of FF7](https://store.eu.square-enix.com/emea_de/pc-windows-download/FINAL-FANTASY-VII.php) ([English link](http://store.na.square-enix.com/DRHM/store?Action=DisplayProductDetailsPage&SiteID=sqenixus&Locale=en_US&ThemeID=29853700&Env=BASE&productID=250845500#.UYgf7r-9Kc0)) have native gamepad support?

I was unable to find anything on the official website.

Comment: Everything I've heard says FFVII PC is the same version they released more than 10 years ago.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the PC Specs tab on the website:

> OS: Microsoft Windows XP/Vista/Seven (32/64bits)
>    Processor: 2GHz
>    Memory: 1GB
>    Graphics: DirectX 9.0c-compatible graphic card
>    Hard Drive: 2.16GB
>    DirectX: DirectX 9.0C
>    **Controller Support: Gamepad / Joystick**

Comment: Yeah, I played it with both a generic usb gamepad, and an Xbox 360 controller. The settings screen in the launcher provides the options to bind the controls to specific buttons on the pad.